# d3.js chart not respecting margins

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

So I'm defining the margins here:

```
  const svg1 = d3.select(graphElement1.current);
  const margin = {top: 0, right: 30, bottom: 10, left: 10};
  const width = 650 - margin.left - margin.right;
  const height = 100 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

Drawing the chart here

```
    const data = timeseries;

    const x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
          return new Date(d['date']+'2020');
        }))
        .range([0, width]);

    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
          return +d['totalconfirmed'];
        })])
        .range([height, 0]);

    svg1.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .attr('class', 'axis')
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

svg1.append('path')
        .datum(data)
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('stroke', '#ff073a99')
        .attr('stroke-width', 5)
        .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
        .attr('d', d3.line()
            .x(function(d) {
              return x(new Date(d['date']+'2020'));
            })
            .y(function(d) {
              return y(d['totalconfirmed'])-5;
            })
            .curve(d3.curveCardinal),
        );

    svg1.selectAll('.dot')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('fill', '#ff073a')
        .attr('stroke', '#ff073a')
        .attr('r', 3)
        .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
        .attr('cx', function(d) {
          return x(new Date(d['date']+'2020'));
        })
        .attr('cy', function(d) {
          return y(d['totalconfirmed'])-5;
        })
        .on('mouseover', (d, i) => {
          d3.select(d3.event.target).attr('r', '5');
          setDatapoint(d);
          setIndex(i);
        })
        .on('mouseout', (d) => {
          d3.select(d3.event.target).attr('r', '3');
        });
```

And this is the div structure of the chart:

```
        <div className="svg-parent">
          <div className="stats">
            <h5>Confirmed {datapoint['date']}</h5>
            <div className="stats-bottom">
               ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <svg ref={graphElement1} width="650" height="100" viewBox="0 0 650 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"/>
        </div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
  .svg-parent {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0.9;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    svg {
      align-self: center;
    }
  }
```

I've tried a lot of CSS rules to allow the svg to respect the margin definition but I can't seem to make it work. I'm unable to show the x-axis also as a result.

This is how it looks right now, the right margin works, however,

[image]

[Edited; even after setting left value the graph does not shift right]

Comment: Please edit the question to add the code portions where the defined margins are _used_.

Comment: Did you notice that in the margin variable, the top and left values are set to 0?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, the defined margins are used when setting the width of the graph. Also yeah, setting the left value still does not shift the graph right!

Comment: We cannot help without the relevant code. Please read and follow [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Mehdi thanks for sharing the guideline, I've added the relevant pieces of code. Also reiterating that the margins are used while setting the `width` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [this tutorial](https://observablehq.com/@d3/lets-make-a-bar-chart/4):

> These margins will be used to inset the ranges of our scales. Rather than extending from 0 to the full width and height of the chart, the starts and ends of the ranges are moved inward by the corresponding margins.

So for the `x` axis scale, replace `.range([0, width])` by:

```
.range([margin.left, width])
```

And similary, for the `y` axis, try the following for the range definition:

```
.range([height, margin.top])
```